# How many tags we are allow to register per device for Azure push notification hub

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I am using the Azure Push Notification Hub. Somewhere I saw there are limit of tags can register per device. Is it right?

My scenario is each device will have numerous of sites which user can go into. The push notification will send to message to the device who have registered of that site.

e.g. Device A may have 100 Sites so the Device A may need to add 100 of tags when register to Notification Hub (May not be adding all the tags at the same time). When push notification required to push notification to devices, I can send e.g. SiteA to whoever device have registered a tag called SiteA will receive it.

Am I using it in a wrong way?

On the website :

> [Azure Push Notification](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)

All new registrations against any hubs within the namespace of whose Active Device quota is reached will be interrupted.

Does that mean once it reached number of devices registered to that Notification Hub, no additional devices can register....

At the moment, my Xamarin form application will call to my server and register to the notification hub.

How do I know when the device needs to unregister from the notification hub when user uninstall the application? Can't remember where I read it, it will automatically unregistered when expired so no need to detect whether user have uninstalled the application or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using the Azure Push Notification Hub. Somewhere I saw there are limit of tags can register per device. Is it right?

According to [Notification Hub Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#notification-hub-service-limits)

[image]

So each device can have up to 60 tags, and each tag can be up to 120 characters.
One device couldn't have 100 website's tags.

Comment: I want to register on hub every user with email in tag for personalised notifications. I am ok with this limit ? Later maybe i have 10.000 devices with 10.000 different tags, 1 per register.